# Codenameone Facebook share through the Simulator

Tags: java, facebook, share, codenameone

Helle everyone,

I'm wondering if there is a possible way to share a text On my Facebook profile, even while using the codenameone simulator.
I did my researchs but all what I find is the share using the "ShareButton" component which only works when you launch the app with an actual device.

Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

The share button doesn't really know about facebook. It places the text into a special OS hook which offers you venues where to share that data. That's great because that means it can work for other social networks seamlessly and it uses the native OS to do the posting. Zero setup.

Desktops don't have an API like that. If you want to explicitly share to facebook you can just do something like this which will launch the browser:

```
Display.getInstance().execute("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + Util.encodeUrl(textToShare));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the ShareButton is actually great when I tried it on my device, but I need to share from the simulator. Is there a way to share directely using the Facebook Token access ?

Comment: You can use the Facebook Graph API to do that but for that you need to get the user to login to facebook. You can check out the instructions of doing that in the developer guide then check out the graph api calls on facebooks site